# I wanna find an Schema name

Tags: node.js, mongoose, ejs

I have an collection in mongoose. it's name member and I use the findOne for find one like this : `var member = findOne(name , (err , docs)=>{console.log(docs)})`
and then I wanna to find more things by member var like : momber.targetNmae in Schema and it not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be assigning the value of an async function that doesn't return anything. Try using async/await to make it more readable. Chain your query after the Collection name like:

```
User.find();

let doc; 

try {
  doc = await User.findOne({ name: name });
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
};
console.log(doc);
```

And without async/await:

```
User.findOne({ name: name }, (err, doc) => {
  if (!err) {
    console.log(doc);
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks. I try a lot for understand how async/await work but I can't understand the idea behind it.